# join of two array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to join two arrays, from the server I get the next json. an array that says "data" that has 2 objects and another that is called "Doc" that is made up of 4 objects.

> I want to create a matrix that contains 8 elements equal to the following (I did it by hand):

```
[
    {
        "idlibrosiva": 1,
        "iddoc": 1,
        "false": 1
    },{
        "idlibrosiva": 1,
        "iddoc": 2,
        "false": 1
    },{
        "idlibrosiva": 1,
        "iddoc": 3,
        "false": 1
    },{
        "idlibrosiva": 1,
        "iddoc": 4,
        "false": 1
    },{
        "idlibrosiva": 2,
        "iddoc": 1,
        "false": 1
    },{
        "idlibrosiva": 2,
        "iddoc": 2,
        "false": 1
    },{
        "idlibrosiva": 2,
        "iddoc": 3,
        "false": 1
    },{
        "idlibrosiva": 1,
        "iddoc": 4,
        "false": 1
    }]
```

This is what I get from the server in json

```
    {
"status": "success",
"code": 200,
"data": [
    {
        "idlibrosiva": 1,
        "nombre": "Compras",
        "descripcion": "Art.-141 C.T.",
        "estado": 1
    },
    {
        "idlibrosiva": 2,
        "nombre": "Contribuyentes",
        "descripcion": "Artículo 141. C.T.- ",
        "estado": 1
    },

],
"Doc": [
    {
        "**iddoc**": 1,
        "documento": "CREDITO FISCAL",
        "descripcion": "ART. 107 C.C.",
        "estado": 1
    },
    {
        "iddoc": 2,
        "documento": "NOTA DE CREDITO",
        "descripcion": "ART. 110 C.C- ",
        "estado": 1
    },
    {
        "iddoc": 3,
        "documento": "FACTURA",
        "descripcion": "ART. 107 C.C.",
        "estado": 1
    },
    {
        "iddoc": 4,
        "documento": "NOTA DE DEBITO",
        "descripcion": "ART. 110 C.C.-",
        "estado": 1
    },
       ],
"mensaje": "Todo se ha cargado correctamente"}
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
this.Info = response.data;
                this.liva = response.data.filter((item) => item.estado == 1);
                this.docs = response.Doc.filter((item) => item.estado == 1);
                this.DocYlib = this.liva.map((item)=>{
                    const DocumentoUtilizado = new ModeloDocUtilizadosIVA();
                    DocumentoUtilizado.Libro = item.idlibrosiva;
                    DocumentoUtilizado.estado = false;
                    DocumentoUtilizado.documento = this.docs.map((item) => item.iddoc);
                    return DocumentoUtilizado;
                })
```

But the result has been:

[image]

Comment: How should the output look like?

Comment: Thanks for your help, the living room I want it to be: 

[
    {
        "idlibrosiva": 1,
        "iddoc": 1,
        "false": 1
    },]

Comment: Please check the answer I have shared and revert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce`, `map` and `concat`

```
var output = obj.Doc.reduce( (acc, c) => 
     acc.concat( obj.data.map( s => 
      ({ idlibrosiva : s.idlibrosiva, iddoc : c.iddoc, "false": 1 })  //return new object from map callback
     ) //concat statement ended
) , []) //initialize accumulator to []
```

**Demo**

```js
var obj = {
  "status": "success",
  "code": 200,
  "data": [{
      "idlibrosiva": 1,
      "nombre": "Compras",
      "descripcion": "Art.-141 C.T.",
      "estado": 1
    },
    {
      "idlibrosiva": 2,
      "nombre": "Contribuyentes",
      "descripcion": "Artículo 141. C.T.- ",
      "estado": 1
    },

  ],
  "Doc": [{
      "iddoc": 1,
      "documento": "CREDITO FISCAL",
      "descripcion": "ART. 107 C.C.",
      "estado": 1
    },
    {
      "iddoc": 2,
      "documento": "NOTA DE CREDITO",
      "descripcion": "ART. 110 C.C- ",
      "estado": 1
    },
    {
      "iddoc": 3,
      "documento": "FACTURA",
      "descripcion": "ART. 107 C.C.",
      "estado": 1
    },
    {
      "iddoc": 4,
      "documento": "NOTA DE DEBITO",
      "descripcion": "ART. 110 C.C.-",
      "estado": 1
    },
  ],
  "mensaje": "Todo se ha cargado correctamente"
};

var output = obj.Doc.reduce((acc, c) =>
  acc.concat(obj.data.map(s =>
      ({
        idlibrosiva: s.idlibrosiva,
        iddoc: c.iddoc,
        "false": 1
      }) //return new object from map callback
    ) //concat statement ended
  ), []) //initialize accumulator to []

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

The requirement is to map each object from "data" to each object from "Doc".

Let us extract them individually.

```
const { data, Doc:doc } = response;
// aliasing Doc as doc, just for variable declaration convention.
```

Now iterate through both using forEach and push the desired objects in result array.

```
const result = [];
data.forEach(dataObj => {
  const { idlibrosiva } = data;
  doc.forEach(docObj => {
    const { iddoc } = doc;
    result.push({
      idlibrosiva,
      iddoc,
      'false': 1
    };
  };
};

console.log('result --> ', result);
```